# How do I call a controller function from inside a custom filter?

Tags: angularjs

I have a function in controller like this.

```
cl.translateCall = function () {
$http.get(`${API_URL}/langChange/` + selectedLanguage).
then(function onSuccess(response) {
      input = response.data; 
      console.log(input)
}).
  catch(function onError(response) {
  console.log(response)
});   
 }
```

I have a custom filter in module like this

```
   .filter('languageTranslate',['$http', function($http) {  

   return function(input) {
    if(selectedLanguage != null){

    /*want to call controller function*/

      }else{   
            return input;  
      } 
  }


}]);
```

How do I call the above controller function inside this Angular JS custom filter? I am totally new to Angular JS.

Comment: Filters don't work well with asynchronous functions. Instead of putting filter functions in controllers, consider putting them in a custom service.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *can* pass the scope to the filter. I dont know how you use the code above, but if you theoretically have :

```
{{ someVar | languageTranslate }}
```

Then you can pass the current scope by adding `:this`

```
{{ someVar | languageTranslate:this }}
```

and call a scope method like this

```js
return function(input, scope) {
  if (scope.selectedLanguage != null) {
    scope.functionName()
  } else {   
    return input 
  } 
}
```